# Scrollbar not moving the image in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to place several images onto a canvas. The following works in so far as the images appear.  However the scroll bars don't work.  I've tried all the suggestions that I can find (in my noobie 'trial and error' way).

Can anyone explain where I have gone wrong.

```
class popup :
  def __init__(self, item):
    popup=Toplevel(width=1400, height=800)
    popup.title("Search results")
    frame=Frame(popup,width=1400,height=800)
    frame.pack()
    B1=Button(frame, text="Close", command=popup.destroy)
    B1.pack(side=TOP, pady=10)
    print( Pattout.findings )
    canvas=Canvas(frame, width=1400, height=800, scrollregion=(0,0,5000,1800))
    hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
    hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
    hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
    vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
    vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.config(width=1400, height=800)
    canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
    canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH) 
    for i in Pattout.findings :
      print( i )
      photo=PhotoImage(file="./patterns/"+i[0]+".gif")
      label=Label(canvas, image=photo)
      label.image=photo
      label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
```

I have also tried `canvas.create_image` (as below), but could not find a way to stop Python garbage collector removing the first images.

```
x = 10
y = 20
for i in Pattout.findings :
  print( i )
  self.photo = PhotoImage(file="./patterns/"+i[0]+".gif")
  self.item=canvas.create_image(x, y, anchor=NW, image=self.photo)
  x += 560
```

Comment: Would it be possible to remove some of the code so that it still demonstrates the same problem, now your question is a bit dense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas will only scroll canvas objects. In the case of widgets, that means widgets added to the canvas with `create_window`. Widgets that are packed in a canvas won't scroll.

The simplest way to prevent the image from being garbage-collected is to save them to a list:

```
canvas.images = []
for i in Pattout.findings :
  print( i )
  photo = PhotoImage(file="./patterns/"+i[0]+".gif")
  self.item=canvas.create_image(x, y, anchor=NW, image=photo)
  canvas.images.append(photo)
  x += 560
```